# MS Access 1:0..1 relationship not working as expected

Tags: ms-access, relationship, sign

I have a main table called person and child tables member, volunteer, sponsor which are connected to the main table as 1:0..1 in ms access. But when I am about to enter records in let's say volunteer, I get the little plus sign from which I can enter records to the main table which makes it a 1:m kind of relationship. How can I resolve this? Pics included

1: `https://i.stack.imgur.com/wyyQM.jpg`
2: `https://i.stack.imgur.com/wyyQM.jpg`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That + sign on Tables only means the table has a relationship to another table. So if set up like your pics above, you should still be maintaining a 1 to 1 link.

To see or change this, open the Main Table (with +) and in the highlighted Table Tools above the ribbon, select Table and find Relationships. In it, you will see the relationships made. These are used to inform other objects (i.e., forms, queries) of how your tables relate and to avoid orphans and maintain referential integrity.

See more info at this [MS Office Guide](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/guide-to-table-relationships-HA010120534.aspx).